# Cannnot convert HTML code to PDF with vue-html2pdf

Tags: vue.js, html2pdf

I have a project in vuejs and I have to use vue-html2pdf.

When I write text the in tag: `<section>something</section>`, my PDF is generated.
But when I write in tag: `<section><p>something</p></section>`, my browser is crashes.

Here my code in vuejs:

```
<vue-html2pdf
    :show-layout="false"
    :preview-modal="true"
    :paginate-elements-by-height="10"
    :filename="test"
    :pdf-quality="2"
    :pdf-format="size"
    :ref="ref"
>
    <section slot="pdf-content">
        <section class="pdf-item">
            <img :src=url>
        </section>
    </section>
</vue-html2pdf>
```

And my function to download PDF:

```
function generateReport() {
  this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf();
}
```

Comment: Consider also, on Linux, [DocBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook), and [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) with [HeVeA](http://hevea.inria.fr/). You'll need to start external processes from your web server

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`vue-html2pdf` npm module does not work properly. Rather than you can try `html2pdf` module for convert html to pdf in `vuejs`.

Package link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js/v/0.9.1

Codesandbox Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xlnzq7y28q

Hope that, your problem will be solved. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you !!! it was really helped to me. Cheers!!!

Comment: Careful! that package has 4 vulnerabilities, 1 of them high:

Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1709
Cross-site scripting in jspdf - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1712
Depends on vulnerable versions of canvg
No fix available
node_modules/jspdf
  html2pdf.js  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of jspdf
  node_modules/html2pdf.js

Comment: xmldom  *
Severity: moderate
Misinterpretation of malicious XML input - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1650
Misinterpretation of malicious XML input - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1769
No fix available

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass URL of same domain to download the pdf of that page ? I have checked this script but not able to understand how can i pass URL into it. Example: http://example.com/about...i want to download this pdf of this page.

Comment: I'm not able to get a copy of your codepen to work in my application.  The method fires when I press the button, but the html2pdf portion does nothing, and I don't get an error.  Any advice on how to display an error if there is one?

Answer (score 7):

I just saw this, I am the developer of vue-html2pdf, and I tested your code on version 1.3.6, it worked perfectly on Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138, Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and Firefox 76.0.1.

you also have a typo on `<img :src=url>` it should be `<img :src="url">`

and if you can, can you please provide the values of the variables test, size, and ref, you assigned to the props.

and the prop `:paginate-elements-by-height="10"` I think the value should be higher, try 1300.

Answer (score 0):

After losing my day I found the problem !
Here 2 sources of error :

-If you use a "component" inside the "vue-html2pdf", the page break couldn't work.
To solve this problem, use "vue-fragment" library <3

-If you use a too small value for "paginate-elements-by-height" attribute, the "vue-html2pdf will bug and then you can just kill the process. By default it's 1300 or 1400, try with 1600 or more and your problem will solved.

Answer (score 0):

fixed this problem: Impossible to convert html code to pdf with vue-html2pdf

```
   the first of all i have set packages in the such following sequence
    1. npm i jspdf@1.5.2 
    2. npm i html2pdf.js@0.9.1
    3. npm i vue-html2pdf@1.8.0

    On time the passing some steps to create pdf file i got mistake
    `TypeError: str.charAt(...) is not a function`.
    or on another configuration for vue-html2pdf i am getting the console messages:
    - Dom Has Rendered 
    - 0ms html2canvas: html2canvas $npm_package_version
    - 926ms html2canvas: Document cloned, using computed rendering
    - 926ms html2canvas: Starting node parsing
    - 947ms html2canvas: Finished parsing node tree
    - 948ms html2canvas: Finished loading 0 images Array(0)
    - 949ms html2canvas: Starting renderer
    - 950ms html2canvas: Canvas renderer initialized (816x18 at 312,63) with scale 2
    - 959ms html2canvas: Render completed
    but pdf file no created
    I fixed this problem:
    when i looked at "node_modules\html2pdf.js\package.json"
    and i have seen
    "dependencies": {
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.5",
        "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
        "jspdf": "^1.4.1"
     }
     then from "myproject\package.json" - 
    I have replaced
     "dependencies": {
     from "jspdf: ^1.5.2" to   "jspdf: ^1.4.1"
     so need to set
     1. npm i jspdf@1.4.1
     2. npm i html2pdf.js@0.9.1
     3. npm i vue-html2pdf@1.8.0
     so you should look at *jspdf version* into "node_modules\html2pdf.js\package.json"
```