# Converting hidden div to pdf in vue

Tags: vue.js, html2pdf

After a few hours of research, I found some of exporting the content of divs to pdf, including all styles. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204249/impossible-to-convert-html-code-to-pdf-with-vue-html2pdf) page, `vue-html2pdf` does not work properly, so i used `html2pdf`. It takes a div with `ref` and converts it to pdf, downloading it at the same time:

```html
<div ref="printable">Hello</div>
<button @click="export()">Export to PDF</button
```

```js
export() {
    html2pdf(this.$refs.document, {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'document.pdf',
        image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas: { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true },
        jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'landscape' }
    })
},
```

The problem is that it includes all the styles and i cannot export a hidden div. Is there any proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `ref` for the hidden element and remove the hidden Attribute before pdf generation and set it again as soon as the generated function called. Here I edit the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html2pdf-0cbh9). You can see a heading in the pdf which is hidden in the [page](https://0cbh9.csb.app).

```
<template>
      <div id="app" ref="document">
        <img width="200" src="./assets/logo.png">
        <router-view></router-view>
        <h1 ref="hide" hidden>This is shown in pdf</h1>
        <button @click="exportToPDF">Export to PDF</button>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
  import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";

  export default {
    name: "app",
    methods: {
      exportToPDF() {
        let data = Object.assign({}, this.$refs);
        data.hide.removeAttribute("hidden");
        html2pdf(data.document, {
          margin: 1,
          filename: "document.pdf",
          image: {
            type: "jpeg",
            quality: 0.98
          },
          html2canvas: {
            dpi: 192,
            letterRendering: true
          },
          jsPDF: {
            unit: "in",
            format: "letter",
            orientation: "landscape"
          }
        });
        data.hide.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
      }
    }
  };
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The data.hide.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden"); didn't work for me, but I redirect to a thank you page anyway, so this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to avoid it

HTML:

```
<div class="noPrint">
    Div which needs to be hidden when printing
</div>
<div class="showOnPrint" style="display:none">
    Hidden div which needs to be visible when printing
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print{
   .noPrint{
       display:none !important;
   }
   .showOnPrint{
       display:block !important;
   }
}
```

Comment: NONONO. You didn't get the question. I WANT the hidden div to be included in pdf

Comment: So, create a class to display when you print.

@media print{
   .noprint{
       display:none;
   }
   .showPrint{
       display:block !important;
   }
}

Comment: the block is dynamic, it shows dynamically. I tried adding another class to show it when print button is clicked, but this doen't work

Answer (score 0):

import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";
The comment above and its owner is tuhin47 that it works, but it is a
the version of
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.2/html2pdf.js
it worked with me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).