# Vuejs + vue-html2pdf: window is not defined

Tags: vue.js, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I can't get the plugin to work. As stated in [these instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf#usage), I imported vue-html2pdf in my vue component:

```
import VueHtml2pdf from 'vue-html2pdf
```

I registered it in my component's components list:

`components: { VueHtml2pdf }`

Here's my methods:

```
methods: { 
  generatePDF () { 
    if (process.browser) { 
      this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf() 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Here's my template:

```
<v-btn class="mt-5" @click="generatePDF">
Télécharger le catalogue
</v-btn>

<client-only>
  <vue-html2pdf
    ref="html2Pdf"
    :enable-download="true"
    filename="hee hee"
    :manual-pagination="false"
  >
    <section slot="pdf-content">
      <!-- PDF Content Here -->
    </section>
  </vue-html2pdf>
</client-only>
```

but I get this error:

> window is not defined

What am I missing here please ? One answer to this could save my job, any help would be appreciated...

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Package Version
"vue-html2pdf": "^1.8.0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204249/impossible-to-convert-html-code-to-pdf-with-vue-html2pdf), I directly used html2pdf (without the vue wrapper) and everything worked fine.

Hop this will help someone !